# Use values of specific rows as columns names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes that looks like:

```
        0  1  2  3  4  5
Groupe  1  2  3  4  5  6
1       3  6  8  6  8  9
2       5  5  2  1  1   0.1
3       7  2  8  1.9 11 2.1
4       1  2  1  1.1  2  1
```

So the columns names are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] but I'd like to put the values of `Groupe` row as columns name, because it's interesting in the context that I analyze the data. 
**Remarque:** the values of `Groupe` row could change, so it's not necessarily 1, 2, 3. so the solution could not be just as trivial as to add +1 to actual column names.

the desired output for the dataframe given above is:

```
       1  2  3  4  5  6
1       3  6  8  6  8  9
2       5  5  2  1  1   0.1
3       7  2  8  1.9 11 2.1
4       1  2  1  1.1  2  1
```

So how can I change the columns names for values of some row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If row `Groupe` is first row of `df`, you can first set column names by first row selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then convert it to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), remove column name and last remove first row of DataFrame with `[1:]`:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:].astype(int)
df.columns.name= None
print (df[1:])
   1  2  3    4   5    6
1  3  6  8  6.0   8  9.0
2  5  5  2  1.0   1  0.1
3  7  2  8  1.9  11  2.1
4  1  2  1  1.1   2  1.0
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), row `Groupe` in `df` can be anywhere, not only first:

```
df.columns = df.loc['Groupe',:].astype(int)
df.columns.name= None
df = df.drop('Groupe')
print (df)
   1  2  3    4   5    6
1  3  6  8  6.0   8  9.0
2  5  5  2  1.0   1  0.1
3  7  2  8  1.9  11  2.1
4  1  2  1  1.1   2  1.0
```